# css3 keyframes, animation of border-image changing right offset

Tags: css

I am trying to animate a `border-image` at the bottom of a `<section>` but it doesn't work. Can you help ?

Here is the css:

```
section.intro {
/*  border-color:#06b4c8;*/
/*  border-style:solid;*/
/*  border-width:0 0 75px 0;*/
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 1%;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 0px 0px 75px 0px;
    -moz-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch; 
    -o-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch; 
    border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 fill stretch; 
    animation-name: waving;
}
section.intro {
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: waving;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes waving {
    0% {    -moz-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch;}
    50% {    -moz-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 1603 75 stretch;}
    100% {    -moz-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes waving {
    0% {    -webkit-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch;}
    50% {    -webkit-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 1603 75 stretch;}
    100% {    -webkit-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch;}
} 
@keyframes waving {
    0% {    border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 fill stretch;}
    50% {    border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 1603 75 fill stretch;}
    100% {    border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 fill stretch;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me in Chrome removinf the webkit syntax

CSS

```
section.intro {
/*  border-color:#06b4c8;*/
/*  border-style:solid;*/
/*  border-width:0 0 75px 0;*/
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 1%;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 0px 0px 75px 0px;
    -moz-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch;
    -o-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch; 
  border-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/50) 0 0 75 fill stretch;  
    animation-name: waving;

    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: waving;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes waving {
    0% {    -moz-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch;}
    50% {    -moz-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 1603 75 stretch;}
    100% {    -moz-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes waving {
    0% { border-image-slice: 0 0 75;}
    50% {  border-image-slice: 0 20 75;}
    100% {   border-image-slice: 0 0 75;}
} 
@keyframes waving {
    0% {    border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 fill stretch;}
    50% {    border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 1603 75 fill stretch;}
    100% {    border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 fill stretch;}
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXSpG/1/)

I have also changed the property to be animated to what you are really changing (not the full border-image)

Comment: Hi @vals the cat is not moving in your fiddle... You left the webkit syntax in your code, did you remove it ?

Comment: I left some webkits, but removed -webkit-border-image; changed to border-image in the base state and to just border-image-slice in the frames.  I see the cat moving !  Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m in Windows 7

Comment: Bad luck, that property is not animatable in Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image